# Rename files in multiple directories to the name of the directory

Tags: linux, rename, batch-rename

I have something like this:

```
v_1/file.txt
v_2/file.txt
v_3/file.txt
...
```

and I want to rename those files to something like this:

```
v_1.txt
v_2.txt
v_3.txt
...
```

in the same directory.

I guess I can use `rename` but I can't figure out how to use it with folder and file renaming at the same time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The result can be achieved with a bash for loop and `mv`:

```
for subdir in *; do mv $subdir/file.txt $subdir.txt; done;
```

Note that the solution above will not work if the directory name contains spaces. Related [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names).

Another solution based on comments (that works for directories having spaces in the name as well):

```
find . -type d -not -empty -exec echo mv \{\}/file.txt \{\}.txt \;
```

Comment: `$subdir` should be `"$subdir"`
and to remove the empty folders 
`find . -type d -empty -exec rm -rf \{\} \;`

Comment: @giskou If you like typing.  A single `s#/file##` rename is a lot easier to type, and is at the right abstraction level. Repeating the same shell loop all your life to rename files gets old fast.

Comment: @giskou: I don't see why empty folders are problem because the `mv` will simply fail. Also, removing an empty dir with `rm -rf` is overkill, you can simply use `rmdir`, it is safer.

Comment: @giskou: having that find command above it can also be modified to do the task: `find . -type d -not -empty -exec echo mv \"\{\}/file.txt\" \"\{\}.txt\" \;`

Comment: It doesn't work for me: `$ find . -type d -not -empty -exec echo mv \{\}/*.m4a \{\}.m4a \;`

Comment: Note that with the `echo` in it it won't actually *do* anything directly, plus it also tries to act in the current directory not just the subdirectories. This is what it looks like with both of these fixed:

`find ./* -type d -not -empty -exec mv \{\}/file.txt \{\}.txt \;`

Comment: suggest edit queue seems full, but yes to make it work, it should be `for subdir in *; do mv $subdir/file.txt "$subdir".txt; done;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm). The command would be:

```
rnm -fo -dp -1 -ns '/pd0/.txt' -ss '\.txt$' /path/to/the/directory
```

`-fo` implies file only mode.

`-dp` directory depth. -1 makes it recursive to all subdirectories.

`-ns` implies name string i.e the new name of the file.

`/pd0/` is the immediate parent directory of the file which is subject to rename operation.

`-ss` is a search string (regex). `'\.txt$'` regex searches for file with  `.txt` at the end of the filename.

`/path/to/the/directory` this is the path where the v_1, v_2 ... directories reside. You can pass the directories ( v_1, v_2 ...) too in place of the parent directory path. For example:

```
#from inside the parent directory
rnm -fo -dp -1  -ns '/pd0/.txt' -ss '\.txt$' v_*
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem pretty straightforward to me:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/sandbox
$ cd /tmp/sandbox

$ mkdir v_{1,2,3}
$ touch v_{1,2,3}/file.txt

$ rename -v 's#/file##' v_{1,2,3}/file.txt
rename v_1/file.txt v_1.txt
rename v_2/file.txt v_2.txt
rename v_3/file.txt v_3.txt

$ ls -F
v_1/  v_1.txt    v_2/  v_2.txt    v_3/  v_3.txt
```

Comment: the subfolders are about 130 and not just 3 :P

Comment: @giskou I do not understand why that matters: I was merely demonstrating that the technique works. The number of subdirs is immaterial, unless you hit `xargs` limits, and even that is trivial since the Perl `rename` will read filenames on stdin.

Comment: I'm more to bash than perl and regexps. If you could explain your technique in detail... I really don't know what it does :P

Comment: @gisou You simply apply a standard search&replace command like you would use in any editor, so `s/foo/bar/g` changes all instances of `foo` in the filenames into instances of `bar`, etc.