# Recursively renaming folders and files to sub-directory name and moving files

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I have several sub-directories with no unanimous naming pattern within my home directory (for example `~/123`, `~/456`, `~/789`).

Within each of these sub-directories, I have two folders named `alignment1` and `alignment2`. In the folders `alignment1` and `alignment2` there are several files.

The files of interest to me are named `alignment1` (no extension) in the `alignment1` folder and the file `alignment2` (no extension) in the `alignment2` folder.

Please remember that in the folders `alignment1` and `alignment2` there are other files named `alignment`, *but* they have extensions (for example, `alignment1.backbone`, `alignment1.bbcol` and `alignment2.backbone`, `alignment2.bbcol` in respective `alignment1` and `alignment2` folders), but I am *not* interested in these files.

```
~/123/alignment1/alignment1
~/123/alignment2/alignment2
~/456/alignment1/alignment1
~/456/alignment2/alignment2
etc...
```

**Question:**

1. My struggle is to rename the folders `alignment1` and `alignment2` to `subdirectory_alignment1` and `subdirectory_alignment2` (for example, `123_alignment1` and `123_alignment2`).
2. Then, in the folders `alignment1` and `alignment2`, the alignment files, named `alignment1` and `alignment2` respectively, need to be renamed to `subdirectory_1.aln` and `subdirectory_2.aln`.
3. Move the `subdirectory_1.aln` and `subdirectory_2.aln` to home directory.

I think it is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306117/rename-files-in-multiple-directories-to-the-name-of-the-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/finding-multiple-files-recursively-and-renaming-in-linux) question, but I have been trying to amend the answers in the above postings for last few hours with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to break the problem into small parts. This piece of code should find all occurences. Perhaps you should change something in the regex. `\1` will match something that already matched inside `\(` and `\)`. `mindepth` should find `*/*/*` and below. The `*` is important here because of the number of `/` you will have on the result.

```
find * -mindepth 2 -type f | grep '/\([a-z]*[0-9]\)/\1' | while read f; do
  <process>
done
```

Now you are iterating all files of your interest. `echo "$f"` inside the loop is a nice idea before moving forward.

If the filter is working, below is some ideas to break the filename into small parts:

```
d1=`cut -d'/' -f1 <<< "$f"`
d2=`cut -d'/' -f2 <<< "$f"`
newName="${d1}/${d1}_${d2}"
```

Now just some simple `mv "$from" "$to"` here and there.

Comment: Sorry, but the code doesn't seem to be working for me. I have tried using echo "$f" but no matchings  found. I think even find is not finding the files -: ..I know that I am not being helpful here as there is no error message to relate to..Any thoughts?

Comment: @Abi Try only find * -mindepth 2 -type f (from the root dir of your search), simplify the grep. The trick here is build your script one part at a time.

Comment: So, this is how far I have got so far; find . -name "alignment1" | sed 's#./\([A-Za-z0-9_-]*\)/alignment1#mv \1/alignment1 \1/\1_alignment1#'. This code is  renaming the folder alignment1 to subdirectory_alignment1 but as you said is finding all occurrences of alignment1, including the files alignment1. I can't get it to recognize only the folder alignment1. Can you think of an amend?

Comment: I have used the selective commands it prints out to rename alignment1 to subdirectory_alignment1 BUT I am not being successful in changing the script to rename the alignment1 files, now in the subdirectory_alignment1 folder to subdirectory_alignment1.aln..Any idea?

Comment: Further development; now this command-line find . -name "alignment1" | sed 's#./\([A-Za-z0-9]*\)/alignment1#mv \1/alignment1 \1/\1.aln#' is finding the alignment1 file in the subdirectory_alignment1 but the mv part of it is not working??

Comment: @Abi one solution I can think is egrep '/(ab)/\1', which will match /ab/ab but not /ab/cd. Don't know your directory tree but it sounds to me that find -type f (and without -name) | grep is the way to go. Furthermore: you cannot use mv inside sed; use the syntax "| while read f; do" (on my answer) to iterate the filenames.